# Binding a combobox to a CollectionView shows filtered out elements. Why?

Tags: wpf, binding, icollectionview, collectionview

Wpf binding is funny for those who know it well and it is nightmare for newbie.
If I bind a combobox to the commented out CollectionView the control shows all the elements, including those excluded by the filter. If I bind the same combobox to a ICollectionView it displays only the filtered elements and it is Ok.

```
 //public CollectionView MyCapitoliList { get; private set; }
 public ICollectionView MyCapitoliList { get; private set; }
```

Here is the code I use to create the CollectionView  and  ICollectionView

```
MyCapitoliList = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listaCapitoli);
//MyCapitoliList = new CollectionView(listaCapitoli);


MyCapitoliList.Filter = new Predicate<object>(isCapitoloMaster);
```

I checked the CollectionView printing all its elements from C# code and it contains only the filtered elements, so the CollectionView is Ok. 
Why do I get all the unfiltered elements if I bind it to a combobox ?

Thanks 
Filippo

Comment: You haven't shown all your code here. Can you just show the code that you are using - and think should work, the collection that is bound to the list, and omit any commented out code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN says about `CollectionView` class...

> You should not create objects of this class in your code. To create a
>   collection view for a collection that only implements IEnumerable,
>   create a CollectionViewSource object, add your collection to the
>   Source property, and get the collection view from the View property.

It further adds ...

> In WPF applications, all collections have an associated default
>   collection view. Rather than working with the collection directly, the
>   binding engine always accesses the collection through the associated
>   view. To get the default view, use the
>   CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView method.

Comment: Ok, but what are CollectionViews supposed to be used for ?